# Rollback a single file in git on a remote repository

Tags: git

Another developer and I are sharing a repository. The problem is that he's using VS2005 and I'm using VS2013 so to prevent my updates from screwing up his environment, I've made it a point not to commit csproj/sln files. Unfortunately, in my most recent commit/sync, I accidentally pushed the csproj file. There are two versions now: the original commit one and the current one. Is there a way to roll it back to the original commit version without impacting other files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can checkout the desired version of the file with:

```
git checkout <commit-id> -- path/to/file
```

Then commit the changes.